# four elements distributing strangly in 3 column container - css columns

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I am having an interesting issue. When I have the following code (snippet)

I see this:

[image: 2x2]

I would like to see:

[image: Something like this]

It only seems to happen when I have four items, three items occupy three columns, and 5 also fill out all three columns.

Is this possible using CSS columns? Is there any hope, or is this what CSS columns are always going to do?

I would consider flexbox or floats but there is a requirement that the items appear to be in order as shown:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

```css
ul {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 30px;
}
li {
    background: lightblue 
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Something 1</li>
<li>Something 2</li>
<li>Something 3</li>
<li>Something 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ul {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul > * {
    flex-basis:33.3%; /*this will create 3 columns*/
}
```

Then, aply an inline css on each child, setting its order property.
If you have n elements, apply for the first n/3 of them:

```
order:<indexZeroBased*3+1>
```

For the next n/3 apply:

```
order:<indexZeroBased*3+2>
```

And for the rest:

```
order:<indexZeroBased*3+3>
```

Comment: My issue with this is that I don't know how many list items I have.  It could be 3 could be 100. (and importantly it could be 4) That's why I thought css multicolumn was the way to go  - - it can handle as many items as I can give it and split them up automatically. Your solution supposes I know how tall to make the container and I don't really.

Comment: Do you know the number of elements when the rendering starts?

Comment: Yes, they will not change.

Comment: Great. I think I have a solution. It will involve some rendering logic to set  some inline styles (js, php, whatever). Is this allowed in your case? If so, I update my answer...

Comment: I would be happy to hear your suggestion (php would be preferred to js) though I am still hoping to hear someone's insight on the multicolumn css issue.

Comment: I updated my answer. I used pseudo code for the formula of the order property.
You can apply it very easily with php. For example, write an util function that will calculate the order index as mentioned given the index of the element and the number of elements. Then use this util function to render the order value.